# Did Edna already know about Jack-Jack's powers?

Tags: character, the-incredibles

In *The Incredibles*, when Helen goes to ask Edna about where her husband Bob disappeared to, Edna assumes Helen has come to inspect the Supersuits for the entire family.

We see that each suit is designed for each character's super powers:

- Helen's stretches with her limbs and doesn't tear
- Violet's turns invisible with her (as opposed to what happened at school, where we see that her clothes sort of float)
- Dash's can tolerate the extreme friction of his running so it won't get worn down or heat up from the friction

Edna also shows a Supersuit for Jack-Jack, shows it in an inferno, and comments that it is bulletproof. At the end of the film, we see that Jack-Jack has the power to "Flame On!" like the Human Torch in *The Fantastic Four* and turn to steel, possibly bulletproof.

For most of the entire film up until the end and even stated by Violet, Jack-Jack was thought to have been normal, meaning no superpowers. Did Edna know of Jack-Jack's powers before anyone in the family? If so, how?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Edna did not know the powers of Jack-Jack. She just covered the basics.

> Edna - I didn't know the baby's powers,
>   so I covered the basics.
>
> Helen - Jack-Jack doesn't have any powers.
>
> Edna - No?
>                  Well, he'll look fabulous anyway.

From [SpringfieldsSpringfields](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=incredibles-the)

Comment: Edna's reaction to Jack-Jack's powers in *Incredibles 2* certainly seems to imply that she didn't know about them previously.