# How come Helen Parr wasn't smart enough to realize how blatantly unsafe the family's super suits are?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-incredibles

In The Incredibles, Edna Mode presents to Elastigirl (Helen Parr) the super suits that she designed for the family.

Some machines demonstrate that the suits are fire-resistant, bulletproof, explosion-proof, etc. However, none of the suits protect the wearer's head, a shot to which will result in immediate death.

Why did Edna boast about the suits' defensive features when a skilled gunman can simply aim at the most vulnerable part of the body that the suits don't cover: the head?

And why didn't Helen notice the suits' obvious shortcomings if she loves her family?

Comment: A skilled gunman will aim for centre mass before trying a tricky headshot. That's the way they are trained.

Comment: Also, it seems like most supervillains tend to prefer flashy explosions and overly complex "shock and awe" tactics over a single, precise gunshot.  Not saying it's impossible to go up against Sniper Man, but you want to play towards the averages.

Comment: @sag Why do you say that a shot to the head results in immediate death?  1st, many fatally wounded persons survive up to years and decades before dying.  2nd, head wounds are only about 95 percent fatal, about 5 percent of patients with gun shot wounds to the head survive.  3rd, only a small proportion of superheroes wear possibly protective headgear.  It isn't the superhero style and even Edna or Helen might not think that much outside the box. 4th Helen accepted the super suits but planned to protect her family by not letting them do superhero stuff, flaws in the suits didn't matter to her.

Comment: Because it's a family adventure-cartoon, not a scientific documentary. -1 for absurd demands for a light-hearted fiction piece.  If you want to go down that route, why did they give the family powers that are scientifically impossible for humans to have? Kind of kills the whole concept right away, doesn't it?

Comment: How do you know they don't in some way protect the head? She fires missiles at them. The explosion would hit the head for sure unless there was some kind of hermetical shield protecting them. Considering everything else these magic suits can do, it's not unreasonable to assume there is some kind of force field covering what the fabric doesn't. Personally all my custom clothes have built in shields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*NOTE: this answer is based off from observations of the first movie only as i have yet to see the second one*

Because what Edna was doing was showing off how the suits compliment their various powers

- with Helen Herr's ability as Elastigirl is that she can stretch however normal clothing when it is stretched will tear and a small snip can create a larger tear.

  - Edna demonstrated that Helen can stretch really far and still be able to take a couple of explosions and still not even develop a slight tear
- with Violet, as shown at the start one of her powers is being able to turn invisible, however only her body turns invisible and not her clothing. if she was to wear a Super Suit she would have the same problem

  - Edna demonstrated that if Violet would turn invisible her clothing would turn invisible too allowing her to go complete stealth without having to be naked
- with Dash, because his main ability is super super speed (as Super Speed there's be a blur on the Classroom footage of him placing tacks on the teacher's chair) when he is running his clothing can wear down much sooner due to friction and with friction there is also heat

  - Edna demonstrated that Dash can run super super fast without having to worry about friction of his super suit against itself or any heat up from it

However, if Edna is smart enough to know how to make these suits could she have overlooked them needing to be bullet proof in the future? i would say no as ***going off the first film only*** with Jack-Jack's super suit [Edna covered the basics, including being bullet proof](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/89863/4297). this probably means that Jack-Jack's super suit is an example of the basic must haves for Super Suit made by Edna before customizing for individual powers (bullet proof, heat resistant, no capes!)